# Transforming a string on hive

Tags: regex, hive, bigdata

I hava a string like the below in a hive table:
`20151201,20151205,1 20160102,20160214,0`

I would like to transform it to something like:
`20151201,20151205:1 20160102,20160214:0`

I may have one or many pairs of dates followed by comma then 1 or 0

Thanks for help.
smr

Comment: You could try with `regexp_replace(string INITIAL_STRING, string PATTERN, string REPLACEMENT)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the final 0 or 1 of a substring of comma-delimited dates is followed by a space (or the end of the line)...

Change every instance of

```
,(\d)\b
```

to

```
:$1
```

Or more narrowly, you could use `,(0|1)\b`.  Although based of your example, both would have the same result.

Comment: Yes, the final 0 or 1 of a substring of comma-delimited dates is always followed by a space.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I have an error, any idea? hive> select regexp_replace("20151201,20151205,1 20160102,20160214,0 ",(0|1)\b,:\1) as periodes;
NoViableAltException(9@[127:1: selectItem : ( ( tableAllColumns )=> tableAllColumns -> 
.................................................        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:71 missing ) at 'b' near ',' in selection target
line 1:73 cannot recognize input near ':' '1' ')' in selection target

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of split and concat_ws functions. First split on basis of , and concat with seperator on basis of :.